# Unity3d - Как создать скрипт с данными для префаба (C#)

Tags: c#, unity3d

Как создать скрипт на C# с данными для префаба который используется в Scroll View.
В Scroll View - ViewPort - Content, на последнем стоит скрипт для создания scrolling menu, вот его код:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class SnapScrolling : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Range(1, 50)]
    [Header("Controllers")]
    public int panCount;
    [Range(0, 500)]
    public int panOffset;
    [Range(0f, 20f)]
    public float snapSpeed;
    [Range(0f, 10f)]
    public float scaleOffset;
    [Range(1f, 20f)]
    public float scaleSpeed;
    [Header("Other Objects")]
    public GameObject panPrefab;
    public ScrollRect scrollRect;

    private GameObject[] instPans;
    private Vector2[] pansPos;
    private Vector2[] pansScale;

    private RectTransform contentRect;
    private Vector2 contentVector;

    private int selectedPanID;
    private bool isScrolling;

    private void Start ()
    {
        contentRect = GetComponent<RectTransform>();
        instPans = new GameObject[panCount];
        pansPos = new Vector2[panCount];
        pansScale = new Vector2[panCount];
        for (int i = 0; i < panCount; i++)
        {
            instPans[i] = Instantiate(panPrefab, transform, false);
            if (i == 0) continue;
            instPans[i].transform.localPosition = new Vector2(instPans[i-1].transform.localPosition.x + panPrefab.GetComponent<RectTransform>().sizeDelta.x + panOffset,
                instPans[i].transform.localPosition.y);
            pansPos[i] = -instPans[i].transform.localPosition;
        }
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (contentRect.anchoredPosition.x >= pansPos[0].x && !isScrolling || contentRect.anchoredPosition.x <= pansPos[pansPos.Length - 1].x && !isScrolling)
            scrollRect.inertia = false;
        float nearestPos = float.MaxValue;
        for (int i = 0; i < panCount; i++)
        {
            float distance = Mathf.Abs(contentRect.anchoredPosition.x - pansPos[i].x);
            if (distance < nearestPos)
            {
                nearestPos = distance;
                selectedPanID = i;
            }
            float scale = Mathf.Clamp(1 / (distance / panOffset) * scaleOffset, 0.5f, 1f);
            pansScale[i].x = Mathf.SmoothStep(instPans[i].transform.localScale.x, scale + 0.3f, scaleSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
            pansScale[i].y = Mathf.SmoothStep(instPans[i].transform.localScale.y, scale + 0.3f, scaleSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
            instPans[i].transform.localScale = pansScale[i];
        }
        float scrollVelocity = Mathf.Abs(scrollRect.velocity.x);
        if (scrollVelocity < 400 && !isScrolling) scrollRect.inertia = false;
        if (isScrolling || scrollVelocity > 400) return;
        contentVector.x = Mathf.SmoothStep(contentRect.anchoredPosition.x, pansPos[selectedPanID].x, snapSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
        contentRect.anchoredPosition = contentVector;
    }

    public void Scrolling(bool scroll)
    {
        isScrolling = scroll;
        if (scroll) scrollRect.inertia = true;
    }
}
```

При использовании данный скрипт показывает только "болванку" префаба, поэтому каким образом можно сделать так чтобы его содержимое я мог менять как угодно (например изменить image или color) и соответственно чтобы в итоге было нормальное scrolling menu.
Если я правильно понял, то на префаб нужно повесить скрипт с данными и объявить в нем переменные:

```
public Image[] example;
public Color[] exampleColors;
```

И воспользоваться в методе Start() - PanPrefab.GetComponent(Image).
Только это почему-то не работает.

Пример желаемого результата: [Simple UI - Scroll View Extensions][1]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class Pan : MonoBehaviour
{
    Image Img;

    private void Awake()
    {
        Img = GetComponent<Image>();
    }

    public void SetColor(Color newColor)
    {
        Img.color = newColor;
    }

    public void SetSprite(Sprite newSprite)
    {
        Img.sprite = newSprite;
    }

    public void SetSpriteAndColor(Sprite newSprite, Color newColor)
    {
        SetSprite(newSprite);
        SetColor(newColor);
    }
}

public class SnapScrolling : MonoBehaviour
{
    //...
    public Sprite[] Sprites;

    private void Start()
    {
        contentRect = GetComponent<RectTransform>();
        instPans = new GameObject[panCount];
        pansPos = new Vector2[panCount];
        pansScale = new Vector2[panCount];
        for (int i = 0; i < panCount; i++)
        {
            instPans[i] = Instantiate(panPrefab, transform, false);
            Pan pan = instPans[i].GetComponent<Pan>();
            pan.SetSprite(Sprites[i]);
            if (i == 0) continue;
            Vector3 v3 = instPans[i - 1].transform.localPosition;
            v3.x += panPrefab.GetComponent<RectTransform>().sizeDelta.x + panOffset;
            pansPos[i] = instPans[i].transform.localPosition = v3;
        }
    }
    //...
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

p.s. Кощунство, использовать FixedUpdate не для просчетов физики

Comment: Спасибо, но выдает 2 ошибки:

NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
SnapScrolling.FixedUpdate () (at Assets/Scripts/Menu/Scrolling/SnapScrolling.cs:92)


непосредственно код ошибки 1:

pan.SetSprite(Sprites[i]);

код ошибки 2:

pansScale[i].x = Mathf.SmoothStep(instPans[i].transform.localScale.x, scale + 0.3f, scaleSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);

Comment: При этом, он создает только одну болванку префаба, в не зависимости от количества указанного в Pan Count

Comment: public Sprite[] Sprites;   проинициализируй массив

Comment: Попробовал проиницилизировать массив так:
Sprite[] Sprites = new Sprite[6];

Comment: Но не получилось, знаю про инициализацию типа Int, string и т.д, но со sprite не встречался(

Comment: В редакторе инициализируй, у тебя Image отображает Sprite, который ты туда накидываешь. Также и тут массив инициализировать

Comment: В редакторе в смысле в Unity3d на том объекте котором висит скрипт поставить желаемый размер size и накидать спрайты?
Делал так, но все равно ошибка.

Comment: Я хотя бы хочу понять о чем идет речь, о первом случае:
    Sprites = new Sprite[6];
        Sprites[0] = значение получаемое из цикла;
        Sprites[1] = значение получаемое из цикла;
        Sprites[2] = значение получаемое из цикла;
        Sprites[3] = значение получаемое из цикла;
        Sprites[4] = значение получаемое из цикла;
        Sprites[5] = значение получаемое из цикла;


Или о втором (где нужно использовать Getcomponent):
    Sprites = new Sprite[6];
    Где каждый элемент массива Sprite привязывается к префабу из которого через GetComponent берется image.

Comment: Ох... У тебя префаб это шаблон конкретного объекта, все они одинаковые, с разницой в спрайт(разные спрайты в Image). Чтобы тот код работал, который я написал, тебе надо чтобы размер public Sprite[] Sprites; совпадал с panCount. Это разве не очевидно по циклу? Если тебе надо меньше спрайтов, то нужно переделывать цикл.

Comment: Большое спасибо. я правда так и не понял как мне задать размер массива Sprites например в количестве 6 изображений :)

Comment: Добавил скриншот к ответу

Comment: Спасибо, да я так и делал. приложил скриншоты, и то что происходит при запуске. До внесения поправок, при запуске в сцене появлялось количество префабов которые задавались в PanCount, и свободно скроллировались. Но после внесения поправок с добавлением класса Pan, получалось то, что показано на втором скриншоте.

Comment: Что находится в 71 и 93 строчках? Вы на префаб добавили скрипт Pan?

Comment: на 71 строке находится:
pan.SetSprite(Sprites[i]);
на 93 строке:
            pansScale[i].x = Mathf.SmoothStep(instPans[i].transform.localScale.x, scale + 0.3f, scaleSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);

Нет, на префаб скрипт Pan не добавлял :), он в себя включает класс Pan и все? код класса Pan и измененный цикл я добавил в основной скрипт.

Comment: Pan вынеси в отдельный скрипт, и повесь на префаб

Comment: Все заработало :). правда теперь почему - то осуществляется привязка к первому созданному префабу, т.е при попытке скроллить все возвращается к первой картинке.

Comment: Во-первых растяни область контента, во-вторых убери MovementType elastic, и галочку на ответ поставь. Если появляется другой вопрос, задавай отдельно.